# Shared Preferences set null after setting a new value to the key

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Am working on the task of changing the user name, however, when I click the button of changing the firstName and lastName, the shared preference is not set.  This is my API Provider class am hitting :

```
class ChangeNameApiProvider {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _pref = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  static const String USER = "USER";

  // ignore: missing_return
  Future<int> changeName(
      String firstName, String lastName, String userId) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await _pref;
    String user = prefs.getString(USER);
    var _user = jsonDecode(user);

    final response = await http.put(
      '${BaseUrl.BASE_URL}/v1/Users/$userId',
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${_user['token']}'
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'first_name': firstName,
        'last_name': lastName,
      }),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      _user['user'] = data;

      _pref.then((SharedPreferences sharedPref) {
        prefs = sharedPref;

        print('after  output $_user');
        prefs.setString(USER, _user.toString());
        print('after 2   output $_user');
      });

      return response.statusCode;
    } else {
      return response.statusCode;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, this is the Button on the form I trigger to call the above `changeName()` method :

```
FlatButton(
                  // ignore: sdk_version_ui_as_code
                  onPressed: () async => {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate())
                      {
                        changeNameRepository
                            .editName(_firstNameController.text,
                                _lastNameController.text, '${widget.userId}')
                            .then((value) async {
                          if (value == 200) {
                            _showToastMessage("Name changed successfully.");
                           await Navigator.pop(context);
                          }
                        })
                      }
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'SAVE CHANGES',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFD2232A),
                      letterSpacing: 1.25,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Then, this is the repository :

```
class ChangeNameRepository {
  final changeNameApiProvider = ChangeNameApiProvider();

  Future editName(firstName, lastName, userId) =>
      changeNameApiProvider.changeName(firstName, lastName, userId);
}
```

So, when all the above code is executed, it's supposed to update the shared preferences, then pop back to the previous screen with updated Shared Preference vale `USER`.

But it seems, the value is set to null, it's not updating.

Finally, let me share how I retrieve the **shared preferences** on the **first page**  after popping from the changing nanme page:

```
_localStorage() async {
    try {
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
        preferences = prefs;
        _user = preferences.getString(USER).toString();
      });

      setState(() {
        user = jsonDecode(_user);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      log('data: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _localStorage();
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: try after creating SharePrefrence onject in ChangeNameApiProvider class's changeName method instead of creating object outside method. don't forgot to add await keyword where you declare onbject.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya, do you mean that I shift `Future<SharedPreferences> _pref = SharedPreferences.getInstance();`,   inside the `changeName()`  ?

Comment: yes, correct as following. SharedPreferences _pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); also. make some obvious changes related to that too.

Comment: ok cool. let me work on it

Comment: Am getting `The default value of an optional parameter is must be constant`  @VirenVVarasadiya

Comment: you are missing await keyword where you are setting string. in changename method.          await prefs.setString(USER, _user.toString());